# How can I refactor the Switch Statements

Tags: c#

I am trying to refactor the mother of all switches and am not really sure how to do it. Here is the existing code:

```
    private void SetPrepareFiles(
                  ObservableCollection<PrepareElement> prepareElements)
    {
        DateTime fileLoadDate = DateTime.Now;


        string availabilityRequestFile = string.Empty;
        string infrastructureFile = string.Empty;
        string gsQualityFile = string.Empty;
        string pvdnpProducedFile = string.Empty;
        string docFile = string.Empty;
        string actualCurrentStateFile = string.Empty;
        string actualIpPlanFile = string.Empty;


        foreach (var prepareElement in prepareElements)
        {
            switch (prepareElement.MappingName)
            {
                case "AvailabilityRequest":
                    availabilityRequestFile = prepareElement.FileName;
                    break;
                case "SystemInformation":
                    docFile = prepareElement.FileName;
                    break;
                case "ITStatus":
                    infrastructureFile = prepareElement.FileName;
                    break;
                case "ActualIPPlan":
                    actualIpPlanFile = prepareElement.FileName;
                    break;
                case "ActualCurrentState":
                    actualCurrentStateFile = prepareElement.FileName;
                    break;
                case "Produced":
                    pvdnpProducedFile = prepareElement.FileName;
                    break;
                case "Quality":
                    QualityFile = prepareElement.FileName;
                    break;
            }

        }   


        var fc = new FilesConverter.FilesConverter();           
        fc.SetCommonFiles(availabilityRequestFile, actualCurrentStateFile,
                               actualIpPlanFile, fileLoadDate);         

    }
```

How would I refactor this Switch to a Dictionary

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983429/how-to-refactor-switch-into-dictionary-factory?rq=1

Comment: Believe me, there are much, much worse switches out there than this!

Comment: What do you want to archive when you refactor this?

Comment: You can optimize switch via removing a lot of not used variables. To convert current code into dictionary you can combine all variables into new class and store it values into dictionaly with specified keys into provided switch and provide opportunity to assign properties.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about

```
Dictionary<string, string> fileMappings =
   prepareElements.ToDictionary(e => e.MappingName, e => e.FileName);
```

Comment: He need refactor switch to dictionary.

Comment: This wouldn't work.  He's not changing what he sets a given variable to, he's changing **which variable is set** to a known value.  You couldn't do that with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the compiler refactors the switch in your code into a dictionary, because strings cannot be a part of a switch by default. The compiler puts all of your strings into a dictionary and gives each of them a unique number.

```
Dictionary<String, Int32> _CompilerGeneratedList = .... {
    { "AvailabilityRequest" , 1 }
};
```

You switch looks now like this:

```
Int32 value;
if (_CompilerGeneratedList.TryGetValue(myString, out value))
{
    switch (value) { ... }
}
```

#### Refactoring

Personally i would keep the the statement you did because refactoring doesn't makes it so much better but you could do it this way:

```
// Nested Private class
class DataHolder
{
    public String AvailabilityRequestFile { get; set; }
    public String PvdnpProducedFile { get; set; }
}

static Dictionary<String, Action<String, DataHolder>> DataUpdateActions = new Dictionary<String, Action<String, DataHolder>>
{
    { "AvailabilityRequest", (s,d) => d.AvailabilityRequestFile = s; }
    { "Produced", (s,d) => d.PvdnpProducedFile = s; }
};
```

Now you can call it this way:

```
DataHolder holder = new DataHolder();
foreach (var prepareElement in prepareElements)
{
    // Do this with try get value to prevent errors
    DataUpdateActions[prepareElement.MappingName](s, holder);

    var fc = new FilesConverter.FilesConverter();           
    fc.SetCommonFiles(holder.AvailabilityRequestFile, holder.ActualCurrentStateFile,
                           holder.ActualIpPlanFile, holder.FileLoadDate); 
}
```

Comment: he assign different properties, this can't be converted to the dictionary.

Comment: What do you want to archive when you refactor this? – Felix K. 6 mins ago. I want archive a files

Comment: Code which you provide not compiled as "value" not defined. How compiler can convert it to the dictionary, if for any "case" should be  "different" code to assign a different property?

Comment: The compiler generates the code and keeps the switch statement, but with ints instead of strings.

Comment: @user1967113 Made an update, this is how i would do it if i really want to change the code you provided.

Comment: How you update should works for last case "QualityFile", he assign a private property of class?

Comment: Its not clear that it is private, so in this case he should make a exception for "QualityFile" in the loop which updates the data.

Comment: I think author not agree with the exception for this case.

Comment: So you decide this for the author?

Comment: No, author want refactor switch to the dictionary. I think that suggest exception for 1 case it not acceptable.

Comment: Then it's on you to tell the author how you would do it! :-)

Comment: Maybe there are ways for refactor? What adviced?

Comment: If you really need a dictionary look into "Servy" answer it should works. But in fact it is overhead solution. If you need dictionary for performance improvement, I recommend use switch, as Dictionary of delegates not a faster.

Answer (score 0):

Most `switch` statements are converted into `Dictionary` objects by the compiler.  If you would like to do so yourself it's simple enough:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
{
    {"AvailabilityRequest", prepareElement => availabilityRequestFile = prepareElement.FileName},
    {"SystemInformation", prepareElement => docFile = prepareElement.FileName}
    //TODO add the others
};
```

Given that you're accessing local variables in the `Action`, you'll need to declare the `Dictionary` inside of the method body.  If you weren't, you could create a static dictionary to avoid re-creating it.

Then the body of your `for` loop becomes:

```
dictionary[prepareElement.MappingName](prepareElement);
```